# How to convert render from three.js to .png file?

Tags: three.js

How would I convert a render to a .png image?

I've been looking around for awhile but nothing has worked.

Comment: Use [`canvas.toDataURL("image/png");`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a function I use and [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2pha/art388yv/) that shows it working.

```
function takeScreenshot() {
    // For screenshots to work with WebGL renderer, preserveDrawingBuffer should be set to true.
    // open in new window like this
    var w = window.open('', '');
    w.document.title = "Screenshot";
    //w.document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = renderer.domElement.toDataURL();
    w.document.body.appendChild(img);

    // download file like this.
    //var a = document.createElement('a');
    //a.href = renderer.domElement.toDataURL().replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
    //a.download = 'canvas.png'
    //a.click();
}
```